# Diagnosing Angry Birds Crash

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, angry-birds, crashes

I have a Samsung Captivate running Cyanogen Mod 7 beta (Gingerbread).  I am using Launcher Pro and have AdFree if that matters.  Everything has been working fine for a while, I had Angry Birds and Angry Birds Seasons working.  Then I installed an update yesterday (1.5.3), along with about 20 others.  I believe I had the previous updates as well.

Now, when I play Angry Birds, Angry Birds Seasons, or the recently installed Angry Birds Rio, the game will randomly crash after a couple of minutes.  Usually when I am interacting with the touch screen, but I have had a bird freeze in mid flight while I did nothing.

The crash happens where the game locks up for a few seconds and then the screen goes back and returns me to the home screen.

I had never experienced this before.

Any ideas as to what the cause is or how to fix it?  Is there a crash dump/log file somewhere I can check?  Any similar issues anyone has?

Comment: Interesting.  My first thought is that it's CM-related, since I've had no problems with the new version on my own Galaxy S.

Comment: That might make sense.  I'm confused as to why it was working before (still on CM7), but maybe some change in the AB update doesn't work with CM

Comment: I read that the latest Angry Birds uses a newer version of OpenGL, so maybe that version is broken in CM7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ADB and run logcat by typing the command `adb logcat > logcat.log`.  Alternatively you can use an app like [aLogcat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat).  That will give show you your systems logs but then you'll have to figure out what it all means.

I have to agree with Matthew Reads comment that it's probably related to CM but there are so many moving parts and different factors it's hard to say.  Unfortunately diagnosing through trial and error will require you removing CM to see if it was the cause.  I would recommend removing AdFree and seeing if you still have crashes because it could be caused by that.  If I were an app dev that relied on ads to fund my company I'd probably make the free flow of ads in my app a requirement for my app to run properly.

Also, I doubt it's launcher pro.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try ADB.  I've been suspect of an ads issue, but then I wonder if Angry Birds would crash in airplane mode when it also can't display ads.

Comment: Even if it doesn't crash in airplane mode it still could be related to how the ad blocker is blocking them.

Comment: Disabling AdFree didn't help.  Still crashes.  Got a log and I copied the part starting where I had launched Angry Birds: [link](http://pastebin.com/j8PafvrW)

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about these things but it looks like you ran out of memory.  If its not the AdFree it's probably related to CM.  I'd post this question over at the CM forums.